# Difference between SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_CI_AS_KI_WI and SQL_Latin1_General_Cp850_CI_AS_KI_WI

Tags: sql-server, collation

I was reviewing the article titled [Selecting a SQL Server Collation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), trying to decide which one to use for a database, and I noticed two that seemed identical. Is there some sort of difference between these two that isn't listed on the page?

**SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_CI_AS_KI_WI**

> SQL sort order ID = 32 
>   Sort order name = nocase.437 
>   Description = Dictionary order, case-insensitive

**SQL_Latin1_General_Cp850_CI_AS_KI_WI**

> SQL sort order ID = 42 
>   Sort order name = nocase.850 
>   Description = Dictionary order, case-insensitive

Comment: Why would you want to use an archaic code page for the database?

Comment: Didn't know it was archaic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The numbers in `Cp437` and `Cp850` refer to code pages, and using the wrong code page could result in some curious results! I would highly recommend that you use a standard collation like `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` (or `_AI` for accent insensitivity.) Picking a collation however is a tricky affair, and if you have lots of Unicode data, using a SQL collation can cause performance issues (as reported by some) as your indexes will not cover Unicode characters in `nvarchar` fields, or can cause unusual sort orders when mixed Unicode and non-Unicode data is present. See [Collation Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175194%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for more information.

I would recommend that you either stick with the SQL Server default, which I listed above, or use a Windows collation based on careful selection. You will notice that English (United States) is actually the default, I'm unsure myself of whether or not that collation was made into a Unicode-supporting collation or not.

Other pages to look into are the [Wikipedia article on ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) and [Extended ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII) which explain the code pages and their history.